# Multiple field vbscript query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, vbscript

I'm fairly new to ArcGIS and I'm trying to string along several queries. individually they work in same query they don't.
background

I want to query all permit types  rc, re, re/ap, and db; less than 30 days old, and only in certain counties.

I'll be making 3 layers with ranging dates <30, 30-60, 60-90, >90

whats working 
Layer 1:

```
"PERMITTYPE" ='RC' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE/AP' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'DB' AND "DATEFILED" >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

** This returns about 60 results in the below counties

Layer 2:

```
"COUNTY" IN ( 'BORDEN (TX)', 'GARZA (TX)', 'LYNN (TX)', 'KENT (TX)', 'SCURRY (TX)' )
```

Layer 3 (looking for different permit type but works)

```
"PERMITTYPE" = 'OD' AND DATEFILED >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND "COUNTY" IN ( 'BORDEN (TX)', 'GARZA (TX)', 'LYNN (TX)', 'KENT (TX)', 'SCURRY (TX)' )
```

New layer (not working )

```
"PERMITTYPE" ='RC' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE/AP' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'DB' AND "DATEFILED" >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND "COUNTY" IN ( 'BORDEN (TX)', 'GARZA (TX)', 'LYNN (TX)', 'KENT (TX)', 'SCURRY (TX)' )
```

Comment: ** layer 1 returns over 500 results all over tx but only 60 in the counties I'm interested in.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange.  Just a note, but if the answer below worked for you and solved the problem, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer (you should be be able to click a check mark on the left side of the answer to accept it).  Doing this will remove it from the list of unanswered questions so people can more easily find questions that still need our help answering them.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the list of permittype between brackets otherwise the "and" only combines with permittype = DB.

```
( "PERMITTYPE" ='RC' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'RE/AP' OR "PERMITTYPE" = 'DB' ) AND "DATEFILED" >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND "COUNTY" IN ( 'BORDEN (TX)', 'GARZA (TX)', 'LYNN (TX)', 'KENT (TX)', 'SCURRY (TX)' )
```